# does arduino run the print function (print, println, printf, etc.) when no COM (Serial) port is connected or serial monitor open?

Tags: c, arduino, embedded, processing, atmega

Im wondering the print statements in my code are taking up processing cycles when the robot isn't connected to the com port. I am running a time sensitive process and have reason to believe the execution of these lines could be slowing my bot down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It will take processing time even if no serial monitor or other device is connected.

A good practice is to a have a `#define` pre-processor directive in your code indicating whether you are debugging or not.

e.g.

`#define DEBUG_PHASE`

```
#ifdef DEBUG_PHASE
printf(...);
#endif
```

Comment: You'll have to use such a compiler switch anyway, to enable/disable the watchdog. Or maybe hobbyist stuff don't even use the watch dog in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

Of course they are. The MCU still goes through the actions of parsing the format string and sending serial data even when nothing is listening.